# Magento. Saving data in custome table

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I am trying insert data in my table but allways get this error

> **Fatal error: Call to undefined method UltimoValue_Warranty_Model_Mysql4_Warranty_Collection::setData() in
>   /var/www/magento.dev/app/code/community/UltimoValue/Warranty/controllers/IndexController.php
>   on line 17**

here is the saving code in IndexController

```
public function saveAction()
    {
        $warrantiesCollection = Mage::getModel('warranty/warranty')->getCollection();
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if(isset($post['order_number']) && isset($post['save'])) {
            try {
                $warrantiesCollection->setData('id', null);
                $warrantiesCollection->setData('first_name', $post['first_name']);
                $warrantiesCollection->setData('last_name', $post['last_name']);
                $warrantiesCollection->setData('order_number', $post['order_number']);
                $warrantiesCollection->setData('tablet_serial_number',                     $post['tablet_serial_number']);
                $warrantiesCollection->setData('date_purchased', $post['date_purchased']);
                $warrantiesCollection->save();
            } catch(Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage(), "\n";
            }
            header("Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] . "/index.php/warranty/index/thankyou/");
            exit();
        }
    }
```

when i am using getData - all fine...

What i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

instead

```
$warrantiesCollection = Mage::getModel('warranty/warranty')->getCollection();
```

i have to write

```
$warrantiesCollection = Mage::getModel('warranty/warranty');
```

thanks to all